# Java class error

Tags: java, class, public

```
chinmay@chinmay-desktop:~$ javac hello.java
```

> hello.java:3: class readnumbers is public, should be declared in a
>   file named readnumbers.java public class readnumbers
>          ^ 1 error

When I compile any program I get the same error. And now I'm tired of this. Help me out.

Comment: If you showed some code, it would be great.  It's hard to help you with coding if we can't see the code.

Comment: Your error is self describing. Your public class **readnumbers** should be placed into corresponding file - **readnumbers.java**

Comment: import java.io.*;
public class readnumbers
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
int num, sum=0, n, i, avg;
System.out.println("How many numbers: ");
n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
System.out.println("Enter the numbers: ");
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
num = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
sum+=num;
}
avg = sum / n;
System.out.println("Sum: " + sum + ", Average: "+ avg);
}
}

Comment: Don't mind the alignment. Sorry for that.

Comment: mudalov (and a variety of others) have already solved this for you

Comment: what exactly I'm suppose to do? I'm very new to java.

Comment: For future reference, when someone asks for accompanying code, please put the code into the question by editing it. Having to read a block of code as a comment gives some people migraines ;)

Comment: Btw,you are not using any IDE ??

Comment: ChrisForrence okay. Thank you. Next time.
Baadshah nope. I'm using terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class name is `readnumbers` and you have saved it as `hello.java`

In Java, all public classes (in your case `readnumbers`) must be contained in a file name same as the class name

Solution - rename file to `readnumbers.java` OR change the class name to `hello`

**Please note that -**

As per Java naming conventions, Java class should start with Capital letter and should follow Camel casing incase of multiple words, for example

```
Hello
ReadNumbers
```

Comment: Okay! Let me try this out.

Comment: If it worked, you can "accept" the answer by clicking on the big checkmark next to it. It's a nice show of gratitude :)

Answer (score 0):

What part of the error message do you not understand? It clearly tells you that your class and your java file must have the same name. So either rename your class to `hello`, or your file to `readnumbers.java`.

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all.

> Your class readnumbers  should be declared in a file named
>   readnumbers.java.

Basically to run a java code you need to write the public class in a file with the same name of the class. For example if your class is `A` then save it in `A.java` file.

Answer (score 0):

Java class and filename should be the same. That's why you get this error.

public class readnumbers in file readnumbers.java